# Bad Request while accesing Gmail API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I'm trying to connect to **Gmail** but server says:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{test}%40gmail.com/messages:
(400) Bad Request' in C:\...\google-api-php-client\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 110
```

I can't seem to find the problem. Here's the code:

```
$google_accounts = $this->getGoogleAccounts();
if (count($google_accounts) > 0) {

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Client.php';
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Gmail.php';

    $scopes = array(
        'https://mail.google.com',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    );
    $key_file_location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/google-api-php-client/src/keys/';
    foreach ($google_accounts as $one_account) {
        if (!empty($one_account->client_id) && !empty($one_account->service_mail) && !empty($one_account->key_file)) {var_dump($one_account);
            $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location . $one_account->key_file);

            $client = new Google_Client();

            $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($one_account->service_mail, $scopes, $key);
            $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
            $client->setClientId($one_account->client_id);
            $client->setAccessType('offline_access');


            $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
            $opt_param = array();
            $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($one_account->login, $opt_param);
            var_dump($messagesResponse);
        }
    }
    return $list;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
$cred->sub = $userEmail;
```

right after creating $cred where $userEmail is the email address of the user you are trying to impersonate. For reference, see the [Google Drive Service Account documentatio](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)n which uses a different scope and API call but is otherwise similar to what you'd want to do with Gmail API.

Comment: ..but now write
 Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }'

Comment: Sounds like you did not authorize the client id in the Google control panel. See the google drive service account doc in my post.

Comment: Specifically: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Comment: I go by ref but nothing opens- only auth form with "select your account"

Comment: Sounds like you're not a super admin. Are you sure you want to be using service account here?

Comment: I can't understand- here (https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation)  i read that i should go to admin console- but to use admin console i should get google apss account-so: how can i get mail without google apps account?

Comment: Service account flow only works for Google apps. For gmail.com accounts, use server side auth: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Comment: But i have got info by api from google analytics without google apps with the way like in examlpe at the top of page