# JWT google-auth-library - bad request (400, failedPrecondition)

Tags: gmail-api

I try to get emails from gmail by Google API/Jwt authorizaton (by google-auth-library). It's my code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
var key = require('../jwt.keys.json');

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    ['https://mail.google.com/', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata']
);


jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    gmail.users.messages.list({
        auth: jwtClient,
        maxResults: 5,
        q: "",
        labelIds: ["INBOX"],
        userId: 'me',
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err)
            return d.reject('The API returned an error: ' + err);

        //...


    });
});
```

I get the next error for the **gmail.users.messages.list** request:

```
code: 400,
errors: [ 
    { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'failedPrecondition',
       message: 'Bad Request' 
    }]
```

P.S.
Gmail API is enabled.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [400 Bad Request on Gmail API with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760949/400-bad-request-on-gmail-api-with-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a JWT for a single user application like Gmail, unless you have a G Suite(Google Apps for Work domain), and that email account is with in it.

> Service accounts are their own account and they're not Gmail accounts. They work well for APIs that don't need a user (e.g. maps, search) or when you are using a Google Apps for Work domain and want delegation enabled for all users in the domain (by domain admin, so you don't need individual user authorization).

More detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29778137/6890794

You need to apply Oauth2 to your workflow, not JWT.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Comment: If you found a solution in an answer to another question, the correct procedure is to flag this question as a possible duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as far as I know it's impossible use the Oauth2 approach in case if one server calls api of another server. It's my reason of using the JWT

Comment: @daniil_ I think it depends on how you use the Oauth2 approach. You can use https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground to 1 time get user's approval for your app(you only need this once), then only use a refresh token to get access token everytime.