# 400 Bad Request when refreshing token via Gmail Java API

Tags: java, token, gmail-api

Hi I'm trying to implement sending/receiving email using Google's gmail api on my server:

```
private GoogleCredential authorize(HttpTransport httpTransport, JsonFactory jsonFactory ) {
   try{
       Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("my_key_in_json_format.");
       InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
       GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(input);
       credential.createScoped(GmailScopes.all());
       credential.refreshToken();
       return credential;
    }catch(IOException  e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the following exception when the credential tries to refresh token:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Bad Request"
}
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:394)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:493)
    at com.snobo.util.GmailService.authorize(GmailService.java:79)
```

I've tried changing the scope parameters to:

```
Collection<String> SCOPES = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Arrays.asList(new String[]{GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY}));
```

And it also failed the same when refreshing token.  Google's online document is not really Java friendly.  Anyone run into similar issues?

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve your issue, but `GoogleCredential` [is deprecated](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) and you shouldn't be using it. Check [this library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java).

Comment: Thanks.  I've replaced it with ServiceAccountCredentials and it was still not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem based on this thread after searching around:

[400 Bad Request on Gmail API with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760949/400-bad-request-on-gmail-api-with-php?rq=1)

"You should not be using a service account if you just want to access one account (your own). Service accounts are their own account and they're not Gmail accounts. They work well for APIs that don't need a user (e.g. maps, search) or when you are using a Google Apps for Work domain and want delegation enabled for all users in the domain (by domain admin, so you don't need individual user authorization)."

I have modified my implementation to use oauth web flow now. I'm really disappointed on Google's documentation as this matter should be addressed outright and as concise as possible. I'm sure "Service Account" and "domain wide delegation" mis-led many developers to use the Service Account approach for many types of personal/individual account application.